# Using python dtype as headers for compressed csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of tuples with structured `dtype`.  I am using `np.savetxt` to write the array to a (compressed) csv file. I would simply like to add the field names from the `dtype` as the header in the first line.  When I print array.dtype I get

array is an object of type:

```
[('time', '<u8'), ('timeStr', '|S27'), ('person', '|S24'), ...]
```

I thought it might be simple to just make a tuple `('time', 'timeStr', 'person'...)` from array.dtype and add this as the first tuple in array but the dtype object seems awkward to deal with (e.g. you can't iterate over it).

Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT: senderle pointed out that array.dtype.names exists which solves the first problem.  However, ideally I would like to output a gzip compressed csv file without first writing out the full csv file, then compressing it.  np.savetxt supports compression natively but adding the header to the numpy array seems to cause a problem as it has the wrong type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to get a tuple of field names:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], dtype=[('time', '<u8'), 
                                                   ('timeStr', '|S27'), 
                                                   ('person', '|S24')])
>>> a.dtype.names
('time', 'timeStr', 'person')
```

Here's a simple way to create a csv file with the data:

```
>>> with open('data.txt', 'w') as datafile:
...     datafile.write(', '.join(a.dtype.names) + '\n')
...     numpy.savetxt(datafile, a, '%i, %s, %s')
```

Contents of `data.txt` afterwards:

```
time, timeStr, person
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

If you're running version 1.7 or later, you could also pass `', '.join(a.dtype.names)` to the new [`header`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy-savetxt) parameter. (But note that this last assertion is untested, because my version of `numpy` is older.)

You can do basically the same thing with the `gzip` module. It's possible this might be slower, though, because it might be that `numpy` no longer handles the compression. Do some testing.

```
>>> with gzip.GzipFile('data.gz', 'w') as datafile:
...     datafile.write(', '.join(a.dtype.names) + '\n')
...     numpy.savetxt(datafile, a, '%i, %s, %s')
...
```

The result is `data.gz`, which, when decompressed, has the same contents as the ones listed above.

Comment: Oh that's great!  I clearly don't understand the right place to read the docs however. Where should I have looked to find dtype.names?  It's not at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html for example.

Comment: Ah, well I suppose you just absorb these things after a while. I would suggest playing around with `dir` and `help` in the REPL whenever you're looking for un- or underdocumented features. I see that `help(a.dtype)` has the information in this case.

Comment: Can I just add the tuple to the beginning of the array a?  Then I can use the built in compression feature of savetxt.

Comment: @Raphael, only if this is an array of strings, or possibly of python objects (which it isn't, at least in your example). Numpy requires that the datatype of each entry be the same; you can't put a string into a column that contains numbers.

Comment: Oh. If you don't mind I will change the question to reflect what I need as this seems tricky to fix.